# How to scrape multiple pages with scrapy?

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to scrape a table with multiple pages. With the following code I print the first page data:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from indicators.items import EducationIndicators

class mySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "education2"
    allowed_domains = ["data.un.org"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://data.un.org/Data.aspx?d=UNESCO&f=series%3ANER_1',
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        return Request(
            url='http://data.un.org/Data.aspx?d=UNESCO&f=series%3ANER_1',
            callback=self.parse_table
        )

    def parse_table(self,response):
        sel = response.selector
        for tr in sel.xpath('//*[@id="divData"]/div/table/tr'):
            item =  EducationIndicators()
            item['country'] = tr.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract_first()
            item['years'] = tr.xpath('td[position()>1]/text()').extract() 
            print(item)
            yield item
```

I have written the next code to download all the pages. It is based on other posts that I have read:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from indicators.items import EducationIndicators
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from lxml import html

class mySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "education3"
    allowed_domains = ["data.un.org"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://data.un.org/Data.aspx?d=UNESCO&f=series%3ANER_1',
        )

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="linkNextB"]',)), callback="parse_table", follow= True),)

    def parse_table(self,response):
        sel = response.selector
        for tr in sel.xpath('//*[@id="divData"]/div/table/tr'):
            item =  EducationIndicators()
            item['country'] = tr.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract_first()
            item['years'] = tr.xpath('td[position()>1]/text()').extract() 
            print(item)
            yield item
```

When I try to print all the pages I don't obtain anything. Can anyone help me to know what is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

**Scrapy** needs `parse` callback first. [Scrapy doc](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html)

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from indicators.items import EducationIndicators
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from lxml import html

class mySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "education3"
    allowed_domains = ["data.un.org"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://data.un.org/Data.aspx?d=UNESCO&f=series%3ANER_1',
        )

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="linkNextB"]',)), callback="parse", follow= True),)

    def parse(self,response):
        for tr in response.xpath('//*[@id="divData"]/div/table/tr'):
            item =  EducationIndicators()
            item['country'] = tr.xpath('./td[1]/text()').extract_first()
            item['years'] = tr.xpath('./td[position()>1]/text()').extract() 
            print(item)
            yield item
```

or just rewrite `start_request` method with other callback:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from indicators.items import EducationIndicators
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from lxml import html

class mySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "education3"
    allowed_domains = ["data.un.org"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://data.un.org/Data.aspx?d=UNESCO&f=series%3ANER_1',
        )

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="linkNextB"]',)), callback="parse_table", follow= True),)

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_table)


    def parse_table(self,response):
        for tr in response.xpath('//*[@id="divData"]/div/table/tr'):
            item =  EducationIndicators()
            item['country'] = tr.xpath('./td[1]/text()').extract_first()
            item['years'] = tr.xpath('./td[position()>1]/text()').extract() 
            print(item)
            yield item
```

Here is a code to crawl all pages:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from indicators.items import EducationIndicators
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from lxml import html

from w3lib.url import add_or_replace_parameter

class mySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "education3"
    allowed_domains = ["data.un.org"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://data.un.org/Data.aspx?d=UNESCO&f=series%3ANER_1',
        )


    api_url = 'http://data.un.org/Handlers/DataHandler.ashx?Service=page&Page=3&DataFilter=series:NER_1&DataMartId=UNESCO'

    def parse(self, response):
        max_page = int(response.xpath('//*[@id="spanPageCountB"]/text()').re_first(r'\d+', '0'))
        for page in range(1, max_page + 1):
            yield Request(
                url=add_or_replace_parameter(self.api_url, 'Page', page),
                callback=self.parse_table)


    def parse_table(self,response):
        for tr in response.xpath('//table/tr'):
            item =  EducationIndicators()
            item['country'] = tr.xpath('./td[1]/text()').extract_first()
            item['years'] = tr.xpath('./td[position()>1]/text()').extract() 
            print(item)
            yield item
```

Comment: With that I only receive the first page. I tried to use a CrawlSpider in order to obtain multiple pages but I have read that I should define another method, not use parse, because it uses it internally

Comment: Try to use their API, `http://data.un.org/Handlers/DataHandler.ashx?Service=page&Page=2&DataFilter=series:NER_1&DataMartId=UNESCO&UserQuery=&c=2,3,5,7,9,10&s=ref_area_name:asc,time_period:desc&RequestId=607`. Here is a `Page` parameter.

Comment: And how can I change the number of page in the url to scrape the next page? The request ID also changes but I don't know if that matters or if the url ends in the first ","

Comment: I have tried changing the url (page number) but when I execute it only prints the last page